# SSO not working across browser instances but works across browser tabs

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am implementing Azure AD and need to utilize SSO. After logging in to the website, the user can open another tab within the same instance and it automatically authorizes this user. If another instance (as opposed to a new tab on the original instance) of the same browser is opened then the user must log in again. I'm sure this is because the instances don't share sessions even though they are the same browser. Is there a way to configure Azure AD to allow sharing of sessions across browser instances? Or is this something that can be set in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

***The issue usually occurs if the browser cookie session memory is getting expired. Make sure to enable cache or cookie access in the browser.***

To keep the session cookies active across the browser instances, you can try click **`Yes`** when it asks if should be kept signed in. Make sure you have not included **`prompt=login`** while configuring the SSO application.

You can also create conditional access policy for the **persistent browser** to keep the session active for the user like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Security -> Conditional access -> Policy -> New Policy*

Select the Users or workload identities like below:

[image]

Please note that, Persistent browser works only for cloud apps option, select **All cloud apps** like below:

[image]

For **session**, select persistent browser and Always persistent:

[image]

And hit create and the conditional access Policy will be created successfully:

[image]

- Select all the options based on your requirement and configure the conditional policy.
- The session cookie lifetime depends on the conditional access policy created in Azure Active Directory tenant for which user wants to sign in to and authenticate.

Please **note** that, to create a conditional Policy **Azure AD Premium license** is required.

**Reference:**

[Configure authentication session management - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime)